# CNN-LSTM for price estimation

Tags: neural-network, cnn, lstm, convolutional-neural-network

I have some pictures that I would like to extract features from using ResNet, and then apply another model like LSTM with extracted features to estimate the price.

I have made two folders, one containing all the pictures, and the other containing the price of each of them.

```
input = Input(shape=(480, 720, 3))

base = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False)

x = Flatten()(base(input))
x = tf.expand_dims(x, -1)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = LSTM(100)(x)
x = Dense(1)(x)

model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=x)
```

Now I do not know how I can label the prices of the pictures? I have the pictures and prices ordered, but I would like X = features extracted and Y = corresponding prices.